# Wordpress - custom fields & wp_nav_menu

Tags: wordpress, menu

I want to add a list of child pages of particular parent page in content of home page. For this I tried to add `wp_nav_menu` on custom field - but no luck.

Please advise

Answer (score -1):

check the following code if it work for you.

```
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/including-the-parent-page-in-a-list-of-subpages

<?php
  if($post->post_parent)
  $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->post_parent."&echo=0");
  else
  $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->ID."&echo=0");
  if ($children) {
$parent_title = get_the_title($post->post_parent);?>
<li><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->post_parent) ?>"><?php echo $parent_title;?></a></li>
  <?php echo $children; ?>
  <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply - but I have 3 column on home page products, about, address which am trying to do through custom field. For products I need to wp_nav_menu.